# how to use UIPicker dataSource

Tags: swift

I use the Xcode 8 and swift 2.3, but I met a problem the `UIPickerView.dataSource = (self as! UIPickerViewDataSource)` doesn't work when I try to use func of `UIPicker`, this is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let Num = ["1","2","3","4","5","6"]

    @IBOutlet weak var UIPicker: UIPickerView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        func numberOfRows(inComponent component: Int) -> Int {return 1}

        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {return Num.count}

        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {return Num[row]}

        UIPicker.dataSource = (self as! UIPickerViewDataSource)
        UIPicker.delegate = (self as! UIPickerViewDelegate)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

When I run my code, Xcode warning the code:

> Could not cast value of type 'test.ViewController' (0x1000bd8c0) to
>   'UIPickerViewDataSource' (0x1ab289738). 2016-06-29 15:33:35.079300
>   test[474:98176] Could not cast value of type 'test.ViewController'
>   (0x1000bd8c0) to 'UIPickerViewDataSource' (0x1ab289738).

Comment: your class does not conform the protocol, so that seems a clear case here.

Answer (score 6):

Add `UIPickerViewDataSource` and `UIPickerViewDelegate` to the class declaration:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate
```

and don't use type casting using `self`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    UIPicker.dataSource = self
    UIPicker.delegate = self
}
```

Also you must move your methods out of `viewDidLoad` function, and correct them a bit:

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {return 1}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {return Num.count}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {return Num[row]}
```

Note that I highly recommend you to rename your `Num` and `UIPicker` properties to `num` and `picker`, so you will not mix them with class names

**Upd:** full `ViewController` code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    let Num = ["1","2","3","4","5","6"]

    @IBOutlet weak var UIPicker: UIPickerView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        UIPicker.dataSource = self
        UIPicker.delegate = self
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {return 1}
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {return Num.count}
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {return Num[row]}
}
```

Comment: thx 4 your answer, as you say, i try to add UIPickerViewDataSource and UIPickerViewDelegate to the class declaration, but Xcode warming again:Redundant conformance of 'ViewController' to protocol 'UIPickerViewDataSource'，other code was fixed, thx again.

Comment: @JhonSteve view controller from my answer compiles without any warnings. Probably you have extension of `ViewController`, that marked as conformed to `UIPickerView` delegate/dataSource? Anyway, you should post all relevant code in order to get help.

Comment: It 's my Xcode warming:(https://twitter.com/jhonsteve1987/status/748415522526498816）can you help me fix it?

Comment: @JhonSteve Again. `ViewController` from my answer (updated full code for you) compiles without any warnings. You should try to save time of stackoverflow community as much as you can in order, this is how it works. Learn basics before asking questions, search trivial mistakes (like this) by yourself; post **code**, not screenshots, update question for this if you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MakeReferralViewController: UITableViewController,UIPickerViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var makeReferralScroll: UIScrollView!

    @IBOutlet weak var userTitleUITextView: UITextField!
    var pickerData = ["Mr.", "Ms.", "Mrs.", "Miss."];
    var picker = UIPickerView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.dataSource = self
        userTitleUITextView.inputView = picker

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        makeReferralScroll.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:0,y:250), animated: true)
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true;
    }

    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField, reason: UITextFieldDidEndEditingReason) {
        makeReferralScroll.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:0,y:0), animated: true)
    }


    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }

    //MARK: Delegate
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

        return pickerData[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
                userTitleUITextView.text = pickerData[row]

    }


}
```